# No such module "UserNotifications" in Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsusernotification, usernotifications

I'm using Swift 2.3 on Xcode 7.3.1 and when in AppDelegate I'm trying to import

```
import UserNotifications
```

it gives me the error that "No such module `UserNotifications`". What is the problem and how can I fix that?

I've tried to run it on Xcode 8 with defined `SWIFT_VERSION = 2.3`, but I get a lot of errors in Alamofire framework, but I set inside of Alamofire swift version, too. So I decided to continue working on Xcode 7.

So, is it because of Xcode versions or I can fix that on Xcode 7, too? My target iOS is 10. I copied inside of supported platforms 10.2 folder, so I can run on iOS 10 device from Xcode 7

Comment: Have you added `UserNotifications.framework` in `Linked Framework and Libraries`?

Comment: To use Xcode 8, simply open your project, find the build settings and set `Use_Legacy_Swift_Version` to true. Do this for any libraries you have installed too. You may also have to codesign the libs.

Comment: @Poles I cannot find it in the list there

Comment: @JacobKing I already did that. But Alamofire still gives me syntax errors =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply mix `swift2.3` and `swift3` in a single project within single target and this is also not a recommended approach.

The error which you are getting is due to `UserNotifications` framework. This framework has been added in `xcode8` so you can't use this framework in `xcode7.3.1` .

Also if you are planning to use swift2.3 in Xcode 8 then you have to use `Legacy Swift Version` if you made it yes then you will be able to run your project which is in swift2.3, but you will be not able to use syntax of swift3.

Comment: but why Alamofire gives me syntax errors if I already set legacy and swift version? =/

Comment: What is the version of alamofire and what is the version of your Xcode ?

Comment: In your pod set `Legacy Swift Version` to yes for alamofire.

Answer (score 0):

TO open swift 2.3 project in xcode 8, you have to on legacy form build setting for target and alamofire both.[image]